# Var variable become null After Function Call

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC Project, I am receiving the Data from WEB API.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["LoggedInUser"] == null)
    {
        var Data = GetPublicationsData();
        return View(Data);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
public ProductCategoryInfo GetPublicationsData()
{
    ProductCategoryInfo model = new ProductCategoryInfo();
    // Fetch Data from WEB API AND RETURN MODEL

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    ProductCategoryInfo responses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductCategoryInfo>(response.Content); 
            
    return model;
}
```

From Web API data is **fetched successfully**, But when I check the **VAR DATA** variable, It shows me **null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix a bug, replace   ProductCategoryInfo responses = ...
with

```
   var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductCategoryInfo>(response.Content); 
            
   return model;
```